# How can i highlight update when components render on react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, optimization, react-devtools

I have to optimise a react native app and i don't find a way to see the render's update.

When i open the browser console on react native debugger i can't see the "Profiler" or "Components" of React DevTools that allows me to use that highlight functionality.

[image]

Does anybody know a "visual way" to know which component is rendering when i'm using my react native app ?